# How to use sed or something to remove strings within both square brackets and braces

Tags: sed

We have now some uncommon CSV data file which partly contains JSON data type as shown below:

```
"00001","str1","[a.b.c] str3, str4",true,false,"2022-04-18T12:00:00+00:00","[{""k1"":""v1"",""k2"":""v2""}]","str5"
```

We wanted to remove all characters within square brackets and braces which come together later with no other changing.
But, when I use the following sed command **sed -e 's/[.*]//g'**, it returns undesired output like:

```
"00001","str1","","str5"
```

If it were truly expected, it should be like:

```
"00001","str1","[a.b.c] str3, str4",true,false,"2022-04-18T12:00:00+00:00","","str5"
```

We do not know how to capture and replace the part containing JSON-typed data and cannot find the relative information to do so.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is greedy matchig from the first `[` to the last `]` hence removing everything in between and also seems to have a redundant `g` flag.

Try this `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\[{[^]]*]//' input_file
"00001","str1","[a.b.c] str3, str4",true,false,"2022-04-18T12:00:00+00:00","","str5"
```

Match from `[{` an opening square bracket with curly braces beside to the next occurance of a closing sqare bracket `[^]]*`

Comment: You saved my time.
It really helps to find the final output.
I appreciate you and your guidance.

Comment: If possible, could you give me some explanation about the \[{[^]]*] ?

Comment: @SeungCheolHan Sure, please check edit